# JXInput tutorial or example?

Tags: java, xbox360

I want to use an Xbox 360 controller as an input to my Java program. After searching for a while, I came across the `JXInput` library. I tried their test program, and it worked. But I'm having trouble finding an example or a tutorial for how to make my own program using `JXInput`. When I try to call `JXInputManager.getNumberOfDevices()` as soon as my program starts, it returns `0`, even though the Xbox 360 controller was connected, and the test program that I downloaded was working. Do I need to do anything else before I can get the controller to show up as a `JXInputDevice`? Is there a minimal working example of a program that uses the `JXInput` library, so that I can get started from there, or otherwise a tutorial of how to use `JXInput`?